# Incomplete questionnaires

Tags: sampling, missing-data

Is it recommented to delete the cases from a database if the responses are highly incomplete? Is there a percentage that can be taken into consideration? (for example, deleting a case if more than 50% of the items have not been answered).

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to consider is what type of missing data you have: MCAR (Missing Completely at Random), MAR (Missing At Random) or NMAR (Not Missing At Random).

If your data is MCAR individuals with missing values can be excluded from the analysis and valid inferences obtained, nevertheless, it will still result in lose of statistical power.

If your data is MAR using an approach like complete case analysis will lead to biased estimates. My suggestion, in this case, will be to use multiple imputation. You can check this paper that has some guidelines about the best practice regarding missing data and multiple imputation: http://www.bmj.com/content/338/bmj.b2393